# What is the difference between Marathon vs Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, mesos, marathon

What is the difference between Marathon vs Kubernetes? otherwords, What does Kubernetes do that Marathon cannot do or vice-versa?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Marathon vs Kubernetes vs Docker Swarm on DC/OS with Docker containers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198840/marathon-vs-kubernetes-vs-docker-swarm-on-dc-os-with-docker-containers)

Answer (score -3):

I think you're asking Open DC/OS vs. Kubernetes. If Marathon, it does not include lots of feature, e.g. DNS, those features are included in Open DC/OS.

Comment: Could you elaborate? List all distinct features of Marathon and Kuberentes.