# How to create a Spark or TensorFlow cluster based on containers with mesos or kubernetes?

Tags: apache-spark, tensorflow, containers, kubernetes, mesos

After reading the discussions about [the differences between mesos and kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705201/whats-the-difference-between-apaches-mesos-and-googles-kubernetes) and [kubernetes-vs.-mesos-vs.-swarm](http://blog.outlyer.com/kubernetes-vs.-mesos-vs.-swarm), I am still confused about how to create a Spark and TensorFlow cluster with docker containers via some bear metal hosts and AWS like private cloud (OpenNebular).

Currently, I am able to build a static TensorFlow cluster with docker containers manually distributed to different hosts. I only run a stand alone spark on a bear metal host. The way of manually setup a mesos cluster for containers can be found [here](https://medium.com/@gargar454/deploy-a-mesos-cluster-with-7-commands-using-docker-57951e020586).

Since my resources are limited, I would like to find a way to deploy docker containers to the current mixed infrastructure to build either a tensorflow or spark cluster, so that I can do data analysis either with tensorflow or spark on the same resources.

Is it possible to create/run/undeploy a spark or tensorflow cluster quickly with docker containers on a mixed infrastructure with mesos or kubernetes? How can I do that?

Any comments and hints are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Given you have limited resources, I suggest you have a look at using the [Spark](https://kubeapps.com/charts/stable/spark) helm, which gives you:

> - 1 x Spark Master with port 8080 exposed on an external LoadBalancer
> - 3 x Spark Workers with HorizontalPodAutoscaler to scale to max 10 pods when CPU hits 50% of 100m
> - 1 x Zeppelin with port 8080 exposed on an external LoadBalancer

If this configuration doesn't work then you can build your own docker images and deploy those, take a look at [this blog series](http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/scaling-spark-with-kubernetes-part-1). There is work underway to make Spark more [Kubernetes friendly](https://github.com/apache-spark-on-k8s/spark). This [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18278) also gives some insight.

Not looked into Tensorflow, I suggest you [look at this blog](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/03/scaling-neural-network-image-classification-using-Kubernetes-with-TensorFlow-Serving.html)

Comment: Also look at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator on how to deploy Spark natively in Kubernetes.  It is a very recent development and might be of help to someone.